# Reshape Dataset Long to Wide

Tags: sas

I thought I understood how to use `proc transpose` but I seem to be missing something here:

Have:

```
fam pay quarter
1   100 7
2   20  7
3   34  7
2   54  8
3   64  8
1   36  9
```

Want:

```
fam qtr_7   qtr_8   qtr_9
1   100       0      36
2   20       54       0
3   34       64       0
```

Code:

```
proc transpose data=have out=want prefix=qtr_;
by fam;
id quarter
var pay;
run;
```

I keep getting an error message that "The ID value _7 is observed twice"

As a backdoor way into this, I tried:

```
data want;
    set have;
        if quarter = 1 then qtr1 = pay;
            else if quarter = 2 then qtr2 = pay;
            else if quarter = 3 then qtr3 = pay;
            else if quarter = 4 then qtr4 = pay;
            else if quarter = 5 then qtr5 = pay;
            else if quarter = 6 then qtr6 = pay;
            else if quarter = 7 then qtr7 = pay;
            else if quarter = 8 then qtr8 = pay;
            else if quarter = 9 then qtr9 = pay;
            else if quarter = 10 then qtr10 = pay;
            else if quarter = 11 then qtr11 = pay;
run;
```

But, I would still need to collapse the rows, which I can't figure out how to do.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

First, to use a `by` statement you need to have sorted the data set.

```
proc sort data=have;
by fam quarter;
run;
```

Then try your transpose code.

Comment: Yep. Voting to close ("Bug/Typo") because it's effectively a typo to miss a proc sort as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Should say I had the proc sort in an earlier section which I forgot to paste. Should I delete (because there was an error in the source data) to close out question? Thanks

Comment: I would say mark it closed or answered.  It is instructive for anyone else searching for that error.

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't get that error, if you actually use the `by` statement [you should get a 'not sorted' error].  I assume there was more than was stated above.